# Git GUI push button does not work

Tags: git, github, git-gui

I was copying my repository to github from my local computer using the command - 
git push origin master, after cd-ing into my repo directory.

When, I tried this using Git gui, I can scan for changes to the repo and commit them.
But I cannot push them to my remote repository. How do I find out the reason for 
this error and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you didn't add (`git add`) your changes before doing your `git push`.

That would explain why:

- you still see said changes in the Git Gui
- you cannot push them (since nothing is yet added)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the URL of your remote github to the field "Destination Repository" - for example "https://github.com/[repositury name]"